# Failing to retrieve fabric repository

Tags: fabric

I need to install fabric in a Linux(debian-wheezy) machine.
But it cn't find the repository; I've already run "apt-get update", but it doesn't find any fabric, even with "apt-cache search fabric".

And I have it on ubuntu.. how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fabric` package is not available in Debian. You could use the Ubuntu .deb file to install it on Debian.
But as the packaged fabric version is quite outdated I would recommend to install fabric the following way:

```
apt-get install python-setuptools  # for easy_install
easy_install pip
pip install fabric
```